# PHP not recognizing JS variable as null

Tags: javascript, php

I have a javascript variable that I'm trying to send to a PHP function as null in order to test how it's registering in PHP, however, no matter what I've tried PHP won't register it as null. I've tried:

```
let testValue = null
```

and

```
let testValue = NULL
```

but the first still registers with PHP as not being null and the 2nd fails in my console and says NULL is not defined

PHP is looking for it like so:

```
    if(is_null($testValue)){
        dd('null');
    }else{
        dd('not null');
    }
```

why won't the PHP function recognize my first example as being null?

UPDATE:
JS Code with axios call:

```
let testValue = null;

axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: test,
  data:{
    testValue: testValue
  }
}).then(function (response) {
}).then function (error) {
});
```

PHP controller

```
public function testingCall(Request $r){
  $testValue = $r->testValue;

  var_dump($testValue);
  
  if(is_null($testValue)){
        dd('null');
    }else{
        dd('not null');
    }
}
```

Comment: @Syscall Not really, because the JS here is in an html file while the PHP code here is in its own separate controller. THe data (testValue) is being sent in an axios call to php. So if I dump it out in php it reads null, which I feel like the PHP code should register in is_null

Comment: What do you get if you do `var_dump($testValue);`?

Comment: @aynber it prints ```string(0) "" ```

Comment: Can you show your javascript code as well, with the axios code? I'm not sure if it's converting the null to an empty string with axios or something else.

Comment: Are you trying to send the JS variable to your PHP script using AJAX?

Comment: @aynber I've updated with more complete axios and PHP code just to be safe

Comment: @ArRakin yes I've updated with axios code now

Comment: Check your network tool to see what axios actually sends. Likely it just sends an empty parameter. PHP may interpret that as an empty string rather than null, depending on what's parsing the POST variables (which we can't see) - are you using a PHP framework?

Comment: @ADyson using laravel, but when I check the network payload on send it shows ```testvalue: null```

Comment: Then it must be down to how Laravel chooses to interpret that.

Comment: @ADyson so is there a better way to mutate it in the JS before the call where is_null will register properly?

Comment: There's a middleware that converts empty strings to null (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#input-trimming-and-normalization), though that's the opposite of what's happening here. But maybe you need to make sure that middleware is enabled so that it works properly?

Comment: That's a good point, I may do that. FOr now I just changed is_null to check for empty strings as a workaround and that worked out

Comment: Typical POST encodings (the ones you can use from an HTML form) are text only and don't have the concept of `null`. You need to either use some typed encoding format such as JSON, or map empty string to null.